# Вдруг неожиданно

Tags: лексика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, стоит ли применять эти два слова вместе? С одной стороны, они усиливают эффект, с другой стороны, как я понимаю, применяются вместе достаточно редко. Не является ли это "маслом масляным"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что слова "вдруг неожиданно" в какой-то мере составляют устойчивое сочетание, при этом они имеют разные оттенки значений. "Неожиданно" относится к событию, которого вообще не ждут, а "вдруг" обозначает "неожиданность" в данный момент времени.

Вот уже приведенный пример: "Наполеон опять взял табакерку, молча прошелся несколько раз по комнате и вдруг неожиданно подошел к Балашеву". Во-первых, никто не ожидал, что Наполеон вообще подойдет к Балашеву, а во-вторых - что это произойдет  в данный момент времени.

Убедиться в том, что "вдруг неожиданно" не является тавтологией, можно, если из приведенных примеров попробовать убрать одно из слов, при этом текст потеряет важную смысловую составляющую.

Кстати, это сочетание применяется часто, в том числе современными авторами (около 600 примеров дается в Нацкорпусе), например:

Весь март было холодно, а тут вдруг неожиданно потеплело, и «разверзлись хляби небесные», как говорила бабушка (Татьяна Устинова, 2003).

Довольно часто мы видели такую типичную уличную сцену: идёт вполне прилично одетый человек, типа мелкого или среднего служащего, и вдруг неожиданно ныряет головой в мусорную корзину, достаёт оттуда несмятую газету, кладёт её себе под мышку или в портфель, чтобы потом читать и где-нибудь опять бросить. [Владимир Голяховский. Русский доктор в Америке (1984-2001)].

Answer (score 3):

Да, в современном русском языке это воспринимается как ошибка - смысловая тавтология, плеоназм,- несмотря на то что даже у классиков встречается такое выражение.  *Вдруг* - это и есть *неожиданно*.

Answer (score 1):

Едва ли усиливают... А вообще-то надо смотреть в контексте.

Comment: Немного правленый оригинал: " Она вдруг неожиданно взяла его под руку." Вся сцена достаточно напряжённая и драматичная. Хочется лишний раз подчеркнуть это.

Comment: Не впечатляет. Нельзя ли эту напряженность выразить без потерь в стилистике?

Comment: Что именно не впечатляет? Пардон, на самом деле не понимаю ответ. Напряжённость в сцене на восемь страниц. А "под руку" - это лишь одно действие. Но действие необходимое. Оно даёт толчок дальнейшему развитию сюжета и объясняет психологические аспекты дальнейших поступков героев.

Comment: Ну и ради бога. Зачем ради этого корежить язык? Эпизод, думаю, не стал ярче из-за языковой погрешности... Пардон, может быть, произведение станет какой-нибудь такой вехой в литературе, что литературоведы его станут изучать под микроскопом и восхищаться: вот ведь как! Какое новаторство, какой передовой стиль!

Comment: Прошу уточнить - это всё-таки "языковая погрешность"? Ошибка?

Comment: Мне кажется, что да.

Comment: Хотелось бы знать точно. Я не тешу себя мыслью, что мою писанину кто-то будет читать, но надо, хотя бы, сделать так, чтобы всё было по правилам!

Answer (score 1):

> …с другой стороны, как я понимаю, применяются вместе достаточно редко.

**Редко?!**

Несколько примеров из [**Нацкорпуса**:](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%C2%E4%F0%F3%E3%20%ED%E5%EE%E6%E8%E4%E0%ED%ED%EE&p=0)

> *...своему наилучшему другу, с которым несколько лет не видались и который **вдруг неожиданно** к нам приехал.* [**Н. В. Гоголь.**
>   Выбранные места из переписки с друзьями (1843-1847)]
>
> *Гедеоновский также не находил слов и только головой качал, ― но **вдруг неожиданно** зевнул и едва успел прикрыть рот рукою.* [**И. С. Тургенев.** Дворянское гнездо (1859)]
>
> *Я обрадовался случаю поговорить с нею наедине и порасспросить кое о чем, казавшемся мне непонятным, как **вдруг неожиданно** явилась
>   Александра Ивановна.* [**С. Т. Аксаков.** Детские годы Багрова-внука,
>   служащие продолжением семейной хроники (1858)]
>
> *Наполеон опять взял табакерку, молча прошелся несколько раз по комнате и **вдруг неожиданно** подошел к Балашеву...* [**Л. Н.
>   Толстой.** Война и мир. Том третий (1867-1869)]
>
> *...**вдруг неожиданно** спросила она, точно вдруг вспомнила.* [**Ф. М. Достоевский.** Преступление и наказание (1866)]
>
> *Тускнеет, тускнеет и **вдруг неожиданно** пропадет, точно пространство само собой ее засосет.* [**М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин.**
>   Сказки / Коняга (1869-1886)]
>
> *Васька натянул уже на ногу правый сапог, как **вдруг неожиданно** ударил себя ладонью по лбу, сделал испуганное лицо и выразительно
>   засвистал...* [**А. И. Куприн.** Друзья (1896)]
>
> *Илье стало скучно слушать, ― он нетерпеливо двинул свою чашку по подносу и **вдруг неожиданно** для самого себя спросил товарища...*
>   [**Максим Горький.** Трое (1901)]
>
> *― Я не тюрьмы боюсь, ― **вдруг неожиданно** ответила старушка.* [**К. Г. Паустовский.** Повесть о жизни. Начало неведомого века (1956)]

Comment: Кажется, мне больше импонирует мнение классиков, которые не видели в таком словосочетании ошибки. Даже если современные понятия и вкусы говорят об обратном, лучше придерживаться источников, одобренных историей.

Comment: _romandc : Кажется, мне больше импонирует мнение классиков, которые не видели в таком словосочетании ошибки._ ===  В дополнение к своему ответу могу сказать, что  _плеоназм_ "вдруг неожиданно" использовали в своих произведениях не только классики. Ничего плохого в нём не видят и такие современные писатели, как 
**Захар Прилепин, Дмитрий Быков, Эдуард Лимонов, Юрий Мамлеев, Виктор Ерофеев, Людмила Петрушевская, Борис Акунин…**

Comment: Что ж, остаётся только как-то зафиксировать ответ. Не знаю, какой выбрать - ваш или Сивиллы?